# How to call an anchor inside an id in CSS?

Tags: html, css

This is my html code

```html
<ul id="o1">
  <li>
      <a href="#">testing</a> 
   </li>
</ul>
```

I want to change the color of the text "testing". How can I do that. I used several procedure using css code , none of work as well. Here is what I used

```css
ul#o1 li a{ background-color: red} 
#o1{background-color: red}
#o1 li a{background-color: red}
```

```html
<ul id="o1">
  <li>
      <a href="#">testing</a> 
   </li>
</ul>
```

How can I correct my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add `color` to `<a>`, to change the color of the text you have to use `color` property, not `background-color`.

> Avoid using **number** as selector id, in your case it is 'o1` try using something else.

```css
ul #o1 li a{ background-color: red} 
#o1{background-color: red}
#o1 li a{
  background-color: red;
  color:yellow;
  }
```

```html
<ul id="o1">
  <li>
      <a href="#">testing</a> 
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the text-color you have to use the css color property:

CSS:

```
ul #o1 li a{ background-color: red} 
#o1{background-color: red}
#o1 li a{background-color: red; color: white;} /*The font-color is now white */
```